# Identifying possible multivalued dependencies in Tables

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization, denormalization

**Background on the Data Tables**:

The Elliot Bay Sports Club owns and operates three sports club facilities in Houston, Texas. Each facility has a large selection of modern exercise equipment, weight rooms, and rooms for yoga and other exercise classes. Elliot Bay offers 3-month and 1-year memberships. Members can use the facilities at any of the three club locations.

Elliot Bay maintains a roster of personal trainers who operate as independent consultants. Approved trainers can schedule appointments with clients at Elliot Bay facilities, as long as their client is a member of the club. Trainers also teach yoga, Pilates, and other classes. Answer the following questions, assuming you have been provided the following three tables of data (PT stands for personal trainer):

**PT_SESSION(Trainer, Phone, Email, Fee, ClientLastName, ClientFirstName, ClientPhone, ClientEmail, Date, Time)**

**CLUB_MEMBERSHIP(ClientNumber, ClientLastName, ClientFirstName, ClientPhone, ClientEmail, MembershipType, EndingDate, Street, City, State, Zip)**

**CLASS(ClassName, Trainer, StartDate, EndDate, Time, DayOfWeek, Cost)**

These are the multivalued dependencies I have identified so far:

1. ClientNumber --> --> ClientPhone
2. ClientNumber --> --> ClientEmail
3. *(If Rich Clients)*

   ClientNumber --> --> (Street, City, State, Zip)
4. Trainer --> --> (ClassName, Time, DayOfWeek, Cost)

I'm still trying to get a grasp on database concepts and normalization. I feel like I'm missing a few other multivalued dependencies and wondered if someone could spot/explain them to me (if they do in fact exist).

Answer (score 1):

There's no data.

Without representative sample data, you're just guessing.

While it might be true that `ClientNumber->>ClientPhone`, it might instead be true that `ClientNumber->ClientPhone`. It doesn't depend on whether a client *can* have more than one phone number. It depends on whether your application *cares*.

Basing decisions on column names is *really* risky. Instead, base your decisions on what representative sample data means.